# tengo un problema al realizar una media con los datos de una lista enlazadas C++

Tags: c++, poo, lista, dev-c++

Que tal buenas tardes tengo un problema al hacer una media con los datos flotantes en una lista enlazada, el caso es que al hacer el método "MEDIA" el programa deja de funcionar y realmente no tengo una idea exacta de realmente que estoy haciendo mal (apenas estoy aprendiendo programación, por lo que no sé como pueda solucionar el problema).
Sé bien que el problema es en ese metodo, pero no me ha quedado claro como utilizarlo de manera correcta con operaciones.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class Nodo{
    float dato,media;
    Nodo *sig;
    Nodo *inicio;
    public:
        Nodo(){
            dato=media = 0.0; 
            sig= NULL;
            inicio= NULL;
        }
        void inserta(){
             Nodo *nuevoF= new Nodo;
            nuevoF->Lee();
            if(inicio==NULL)
                inicio=nuevoF;
            else{
                Nodo *ind= inicio;
                while (ind->sig != NULL)
                    ind= ind->sig;
                
                ind->sig=nuevoF;
            }
            cout<<"\nNodo insertado correctamente";
        }
        void Lee(){
            cout<<"\nIngresa el dato: ";
            cin>>dato;
        }
        void Media(){
            int cte;
            if(inicio==NULL)
                cout<<"\nLista vacia\n";
            else{
                Nodo *ind= inicio;
                while(ind->dato && ind != NULL){
                    media+=ind->dato;
                    cte++;
                }
                media=media/cte;
            }
        }
        ~Nodo(){
            Nodo *ind;
            while (inicio){
                ind= inicio;
                inicio= inicio->sig;
                delete ind;
            } 
            cout<<"Programa finalizado correctamente";
        }
};

int main(){
    Nodo N;
    char rep;
    do{
        N.inserta();
        cout<<"\n bla bla bla otro nodo (S/N)";
        cin>>rep;
    }while (rep== 's'|| rep== 'S');
        N.Media();
        N.Muestra();        
        return 0;    
}
```

Una vez terminado el metodo media el programa deja se cierra o no marca nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo solucione con el metodo **inserta.**

```
        void inserta(){
         Nodo *nuevoF= new Nodo;
            nuevoF->Lee();
            if(inicio==NULL)
                inicio=nuevoF;
            else{
                Nodo *ind= inicio;
                while (ind->sig != NULL){
                    ind= ind->sig;
                }
                ind->sig=nuevoF;
            }
            media+=nuevoF->dato;
            cte++;
            cout<<"\nNodo insertado correctamente";
        }
```

añadiendo la media y contador de datos.
unicamente hacemos el calculo en el metodo **Muestra**
y con eso quedaria el programa :)